# How to refer to a table of values in a subform in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, search

I'm working on a searching function for my database.  I've created a test DB to figure things out and I've gotten stuck.   When I'm on the same form searching within a range is quite straight forward and I accomplished it using the following VBA code:

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()
Dim strWhere As String
Dim lngLen As Long

If Not IsNull(Me.Text8) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "( [testNUm] >= " & Me.Text8 & ") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.Text10) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "( [testNUm] < " & Me.Text10 & ") AND "
End If

lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5

If lngLen <= 0 Then
    MsgBox "no criteria", vbInformation, "Nothing to do"
Else
    strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)

Me.Filter = strWhere
Me.FilterOn = True

End If

End Sub
```

The above code seems to work fine, however, when I try to place my form in a tabbed pane view and have it as a subform to another form, I am unable to properly access the table of that subform.  I've tried using various methods shown here http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm but I can't seem to get it to do anything more than refer to the particular textbox in the subform.

```
Private Sub Command24_Click()

Dim strWhert As String
Dim lngLeng As Long

MsgBox Forms!test2!Child16.Form.testNUm, vbInformation, "wtf"

If Not IsNull(Me.Text20) Then
    strWhert = strWhert & "( Forms!test2!Child16.Form.[testNUm] >= " & Me.Text20 & ") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.Text22) Then
    strWhert = strWhert & "( Forms!test2!Child16.Form.[testNUm] < " & Me.Text22 & ") AND "
End If

lngLeng = Len(strWhert) - 5

If lngLeng <= 0 Then
    MsgBox "no criteria", vbInformation, "Nothing to do"
Else
    strWhert = Left$(strWhert, lngLeng)

Forms!test2!Child16.Form.Filter = strWhert
Forms!test2!Child16.Form.FilterOn = True

End If

End Sub
```

I'm pretty unskilled at VBA programming, and I've been left with a task of creating a DB from scratch in 2 weeks.  Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: You seriously should try giving your components and variables some more self descriptive names.

Comment: sorry, I just whipped up the test case in 2 minutes I'll be sure to stick to a more understandable naming convention in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand which form contains Command24.  You can find out by temporarily changing Command24_Click.

```
Private Sub Command24_Click()
    Debug.Print "'Me' refers to " & Me.Name
    Stop
End Sub
```

The Stop statement will put you in break mode.  Then you can use the Immediate Window to explore object path variations until you find the one which refers to the correct form.

However, given your particular situation (little VBA experience and a tight deadline), I will encourage you to switch to a simpler form design.  Ask yourself whether the search form absolutely must be embedded in another form on a page in a tab control.

**Edit**: The comment about naming scheme was spot on, IMO.  Apparently you agree, and intend to change to meaningful names later.  If you do it now, you can make your trouble-shooting easier.  In particular, be reluctant to hardwire the name of a form like this:

```
Forms!test2
```

"test2" is a poor choice for a form name; surely you will be changing that one.  So, for now use "Me" to refer to the form which contains your command button.  Then your code will not break when you rename the form.  That's one less detail to fiddle with later.

Still unsure how well I understand your form details, but I suggest you go into break mode after setting the subform's filter and check that you got what you wanted.  In the Immediate Window, try variations of this:

```
? Me.Child16.Form.FilterOn
```

I said variations because I'm skeptical about whether I got the object path correct.  Adjust it as needed.

**Edit2**:  After your code finishes constructing strWhere, print it to the Immediate Window so you can confirm it contains what you expect (or display it in a MsgBox if you prefer).

```
Debug.Print "strWhere: " & strWhere
```

**Edit3**: You're building your filter expression with statements like this:

```
"( Forms!test2!Child16.Form.[testNUm] < " & Me.Text22
```

I would use the name of a field in the form's record source on the left side of the < character.

```
"([SomeNumberField] < " & Me.Text22
```

Comment: Hi @HansUp, my apologies for the poor naming scheme. The Command24_Click is in the main form and refers to the subform which uses my table of testNumbers as its datasource. I've managed to obtain the behavior I wanted (searching within a range of numbers) but I'm still unsure why my above method was not working. I've only included the lines ive changed.
Private Sub Command24_Click()
If Not IsNull(Me.Text20) Then
    strWhert = strWhert & "( [testNUm] >= " & Me.Text20 & ") AND "
End If
Form_test2.Child16.Form.Filter = strWhert
Form_test2.Child16.Form.FilterOn = True

End If

End Sub

Comment: Hi HansUp, I've printed out the statement from my original code, and it seems to be constructed properly.  However, from my earlier msgbox debug statement 
MsgBox Forms!test2!Child16.Form.testNUm, vbInformation, "wtf"
It seems that my original method would only refer to the current information stored in the text box related to the testNUm field in my table.  
I resolved this issue by changing how my string was constructed and using Me.Child16.Form.Filter= strWheret and assigning it the relevant filter string. I'm still unsure why my original method comparing a field of a subform doesnt work

Comment: thanks a ton Hans my debugging skills are pretty rusty, but your pointers definately helped.  Again apologies for my ambiguous naming scheme.

Comment: You're welcome, imprz.  RE debugging, I suggested a Stop statement to trigger break mode.  That was easy for me to describe.  What you should actually do instead is set a temporary break point in your code.  Click in the margin to the left of an appropriate code line (not all statements will support a break point) so that a reddish dot appears in the margin.  Or right-click a code line and choose Toggle->Breakpoint from the pop-up menu.  Either way is preferable to the Stop statement, because those breakpoints don't get saved with the code ... so unlike Stop, you don't need to undo it later.